# Working example of react-apollo 2.0 with redux-form

Tags: redux-form, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

With Apollo 2.X removing redux integration in favor of `apollo-cache-inmemory`

Wondering if there are any example apps using `redux-form` along with newer `apollo-client` `react-apollo` stack?

Comment: How does it affect working with redux-form? I switched to apollo-client 2 and haven't noticed the change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link-state and https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form . So I have avoided using redux in my app.